# i3wm move window to adjacent workspace regardless of whether workspace is empty or not

Tags: i3

I'm trying to figure out how to quickly send the window with focus to the next workspace numerically.

Using the following lines in my `~/.config/i3/config` file, I'm able to bind `Super [` and `Super ]` to move the currently focused window to the previous and next workspace.

```
# use brackets to move window to adjacent workspace
bindsym $mod+bracketright move to workspace prev
bindsym $mod+bracketleft  move to workspace next
```

However, only workspaces with windows currently in them are candidates for receiving the window.

In particular, if only one workspace is currently non-empty, `Super [` and `Super ]` can't be used to *declutter* the current workspace by moving windows to an adjacent workspace.

Does `i3` expose the ability to send a window to workspace `n+1` or `n-1` regardless of whether the workspace is empty or not?

Comment: There is no feature to do what you want. Maybe you will have to do by hand the "get current workspace number"(https://faq.i3wm.org/question/6200/obtain-info-on-current-workspace-etc.1.html) and than, do the math to move (n+1)...

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want (amongst other things).

```
i3-ws.py move 3
```

It's here: http://bhepple.com/doku/doku.php?id=unixscripts:0-intro

```
$ i3-ws.py -h 

i3-ws.py [up|down|next|prev] [go|move]
i3-ws.py [go|move] number
i3-ws.py open
i3-ws.py dynamic [go|move]

'open' uses dmenu to prompt for an application to run
'dynamic' uses dmenu to prompt for a workspace number
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$Mod + Shift + '<Your Workspace Number>'` to move the window to specified workspace !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
bindsym $mod+ctrl+Shift+Left move to workspace prev
bindsym $mod+ctrl+Shift+Right move to workspace next
```

This did the job for me.